# Julia select a group from a grouped Data Frame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have the following DataFrame with 3 columns `a, b, c`. I grouped the DF by c

```
dfByC = groupby(df, [:C])
```

How can I select a group from `dfByC` for a certain value of `c`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do:

```
dfByC[(the_value_you_have,)]
```

or

```
dfByC[(C=the_value_you_have,)]
```

or

```
dfByC[Dict(:C => the_value_you_have)]
```

In essence - you can do such selection by passing a `Tuple`, a `NamedTuple` or a dictionary.

The reason why it is not allowed to just write `dfByC[the_value_you_have]` is that you can also index `GroupedDataFrame` by integer, where you get the consecutive group, so we need some wrapper to disambiguate. Also if you `groupby` multiple columns you need some wrapper to keep them together.

Also group selection by grouping variable value is fast (so you can safely write a code where you do millions of such lookups and it will be efficient).